# Deployed wsp in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, deployment, solution-package

I created a wsp in Visual Studio 2012 in my Dev server, I copied the file in my Prod server

`(C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN folder)`

and I ran successfully in a command prompt with local admin privileges:

```
stsadm.exe -o addsolution -filename "solutionname.wsp"
```

From the central admin on Prod server ("manage farm solutions") I deployed the solution.

Problem: when I try to open the URL `http://servername/_layouts/15/solutionname/page.aspx` ... "the webpage cannot be found".

The above process used the work perfectly in SharePoint 2010 but it doesn't work in SharePoint 2013. Do I miss something?

Thank you.

Comment: from the central admin> system settings > manage farm solutions and check if your solution's status is says deployed? aslo you have to activate it on site level.

Comment: I understand its production server. still you can check  SharePoint Administrator services are running.. If services are stop your then WSP not going to deploying.

Comment: Waqas - yes the solution says deployed.

Comment: I-touch - the solution was deployed, when I go to the URL I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue: the production server is a new SharePoint 2013 machine, a site collection was not created in the system. When an wsp solution that uses just aspx pages is deployed it will not work if there is no site collection created in the system.

Answer (score 2):

When you are deploying a SharePoint solution via Cmdlet, you should be aware of that the PowerShell Cmdlet does not activate the features automatically it's not like Visual Studio So you should follow the mentioned steps to deploy your solution using PowerShell .

- Add The Solution

  `Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath c:\contoso_solution.wsp`
- Deploy the solution

  `Install-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp -GACDeployment
  -CompatibilityLevel 15`
- If feature is Site Feature : Then manually activate the features at Site Setting > Manage site collection features > Activate your feature
- If feature is Web Feature : Then manually activate the features at Site Setting > Manage site features > Activate your feature

Comment: M.Qassas - there are no features to activate at the site or web level (in Visual Studio I have just aspx pages, I control the application from these aspx pages). Also, is my understanding that when you create an empty sharepoint project in Visual Studio 2012 the compatibility level is 15 by default so is not relevant if I deploy the solution using "install-spsolution" like you mentioned above or use stsadm ... the result is identical.